# How to tag AWS resources using the variables defined in vars_file on ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, tags, amazon-iam

I am trying to create an IAM role with tag by Ansible using the following task.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - variables.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Create IAM role for EKS cluster
      community.aws.iam_role:
        name: eks-role
        state: present
        tags:
          "{{ global_tags.created_by.name }}": "{{ global_tags.created_by.value }}"
        wait: true
        assume_role_policy_document: "{{ lookup('file','iam-resources/eks-role_assume_role_policy_document.json') }}"
        managed_policies:
          - AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
      register: eks_role_created
```

However, I got an error when

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateRole operation: 1 validation error detected: Value '{{ global_tags.created_by.name }}' at 'tags.1.member.key' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\p{L}\p{Z}\p{N}_.:/=+\-@]+
```

This is how I defined the variable in variables.yml

```
global_tags:
  created_by:
    name: owner
    value: ansible
```

I tried to print "{{ global_tags.created_by.name }}" and "{{ global_tags.created_by.value }}" by debug msg which works fine. Can anyone tell the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message and an empirical guess, it seems that the content of the [`tags` attribute for iam_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/iam_role_module.html#parameter-tags) is passed directly to the module and that keys in you dict are not going through the jinja2 template system.

There are several workarounds to this problem but I'll focus on the ones which look the best to me in this situation.

To start with, you could simply modify your `global_tags` variable as follow:

```yaml
global_tags:
  created_by:
    owner: ansible
```

And then in your task:

```yaml
    - name: Create IAM role for EKS cluster
      community.aws.iam_role:
        # cut for legibility
        tags: "{{ global_tags.created_by }}"
        # cut
```

If you do not want to change your source var, an other solution in that case would be to construct the entire dict inside a single jinja2 template var:

```yaml
    - name: Create IAM role for EKS cluster
      community.aws.iam_role:
        # cut for legibility
        tags: "{{ {global_tags.created_by.name: global_tags.created_by.value} }}"
        # cut
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because the task tag syntax contains an error.
This is happening because the tag key is expected to be a string and not a Jinja2 expression. You may want to consider to:

```yaml
# Omitted for clarity
        tags:
          owner: "{{ global_tags.created_by.value }}"
# Omitted for clarity
```

Please see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/iam_role_module.html#parameter-tags

Comment: I need the key name is also from the variables.yml instead of hardcoded it to "owner".